# Segmentation fault when creating object

Tags: c++

I have a problem with creating object on pointer.

```
include <iostream>

class foo
{
int bar;
};

class List
{
public:
  class foo * foo;
  class List * next;
};

main()
{
  class List * Head;
  Head->foo = new foo;
  return 0;
};
```

After creating new foo() on Head program encounters segmentation fault.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason I'm missing why you are repeating the `class` keyword all over the place?

Comment: @Torbjörn It is optional in C++ when declaring variables like "foo", "next" and "Head", It can be omitted (but not in the class declaration, of course)

Answer (score 3):

Make the `main` like this:

```
main()
{
    class List * Head = new List; //this line is modified
    Head->foo = new foo;
    return 0;
};
```

The error is because you declare `Head` as a pointer to an object of the class `List`, but you don't allocate it (using `new` for example).